# Border around Dynamic Range

Tags: vba, excel, border

My maximum data range is `C34:S64`, columns with values are placed from left to the right. Number of columns and rows will vary (but amount of rows will be the same for all columns).

I'm using `xlDown` and `xlToRight` to find first blank cell as follows:

`Lastrow = Range("C34").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)`
`Lastcol = Range("C34").End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 1)`

I'm struggling with putting that informations into border
How can I limit `Lastrow` and `Lastcol` to `C64` and `S34`?

My table is surronded with other data, that's how it looks like
[image: sheet]

Comment: Is it because `lastRow` and `lastcol` are giving you rows greater than 34 and 64? If you want to limit them, why not just use that as the lastrow/lastcol?  Also, instead try this `lastCol = Cells(1,Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column` (assuming you have headers), and `lastRow = cells(rows.count,3).End(xlup).Row` assuming your column C has the most data.

Comment: To explain myself better here's how my data looks like. Circled in yellow is what I want to put border around. [link](http://oi67.tinypic.com/29esq49.jpg)

Comment: Use BruceWayne's proposed method and check afterwards that `Lastrow` is not smaller than 3 and `Lastcol` not smaller than 19 (column S). If they are, adjust them to their respective minimum.

Comment: Are rows 51 through 64 hidden rows?

Comment: What's in row 33 and 51?  Are they still times? If not, we can use the format of those cells (`01:00:00`) to find the first and last, since you definitely don't want to use my suggestion (I didn't realize it was surrounded by other data).

Comment: Yes, I wrote VBA to import data from another sheet into this table, empty rows are hidden automatically. Row 33 is table header. That's how it looks like unhidden [link](http://oi66.tinypic.com/2rn7jnt.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To determine the range you want to highlight let's create a couple of helper functions

```
Function MyMax(p_x As Integer, p_y As Integer) As Integer
    If p_x >= p_y Then MyMax = p_x Else MyMax = p_y
End Function

Function GetRange(p_StartRange As Range, p_MaxRow As Integer, p_MaxCol As Integer) As Range
    Dim lRow as Integer
    lRow = MyMax(p_StartRange.End(xlDown).Row, p_MaxRow)

    Dim lCol as Integer
    lCol = MyMax(p_StartRange.End(xlToRight).Column, p_MaxCol)
    Set GetRange = Range(Cells(p_StartRange.Row, p_StartRange.Column), Cells(lRow, lCol))
End Function
```

And then in your code

```
Dim rngData As Range: Set rngData = GetRange(Range("C34"), 64, 19)
```

Answer (score 0):

To find the last used row, try this.

```
Sub FindingLastRow()

'PURPOSE: Different ways to find the last row number of a range
'SOURCE: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long

Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

'Ctrl + Shift + End
  LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

'Using UsedRange
  sht.UsedRange 'Refresh UsedRange
  LastRow = sht.UsedRange.Rows(sht.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row

'Using Table Range
  LastRow = sht.ListObjects("Table1").Range.Rows.Count

'Using Named Range
  LastRow = sht.Range("MyNamedRange").Rows.Count

'Ctrl + Shift + Down (Range should be first cell in data set)
  LastRow = sht.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

End Sub
```

Also, to find the last used column, check this out.

```
Sub FindingLastColumn()

'PURPOSE: Different ways to find the last column number of a range
'SOURCE: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim LastColumn As Long

Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

'Ctrl + Shift + End
  LastColumn = sht.Cells(7, sht.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

'Using UsedRange
  sht.UsedRange 'Refresh UsedRange
  LastColumn = sht.UsedRange.Columns(sht.UsedRange.Columns.Count).Column

'Using Table Range
  LastColumn = sht.ListObjects("Table1").Range.Columns.Count

'Using Named Range
  LastColumn = sht.Range("MyNamedRange").Columns.Count

'Ctrl + Shift + Right (Range should be first cell in data set)
  LastColumn = sht.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Columns.Count

End Sub
```